# Device dimensions in Kotlin not java

Tags: android, kotlin, device, dimensions

How do I calculate the dimensions of an Android device in kotlin?

I have tried:

```
val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
 
var width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
var height = displayMetrics.heightPixels
```

It gives me the following error:

```
"getter for defaultDisplay: Display!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java:"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the docs for [`WindowManager.getDefaultDisplay()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/WindowManager?hl=en#getDefaultDisplay()) you'll find that there's a suggestion on what to use instead:

> Deprecated: Use [`Context#getDisplay()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Context.html#getDisplay()) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The new way to do it now is with context, This method is the one I used to obtain the real height, depending on the orientation of the screen

**Note * Make sure for the context of an activity or fragment**

```
fun getDisplayHeight(context: Context): Int {


   val windowManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
   val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()


    try {

        context.display?.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics)
    } catch (e: NoSuchMethodError) {
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics)
    }


    return if (context.resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            minOf(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels)
        } else {
            maxOf(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels)
        }

}
```

Comment: Check your  code please. It gives `Unresolved reference: context`

Comment: @August I just updated my answer I hope it solves your problem, and where do you get the context from?

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. I also needed to set `minSdkVersion 30`

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following documentation for more details.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/WindowManager?hl=en#getDefaultDisplay()

[image]

Comment: Don't screenshot text unless really necessary, see https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10563/discouraging-screenshots-of-questions-at-least-the-textual-part and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged. With that in mind, this is strictly worse than Egor's earlier answer.

Comment: Please don't just copy paste the documentation, give a complete example.